# ReactJS and JSX Conditional IF

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to check in JSX if my price var is bigger then 0 and if it is show the price box ... I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
export default ({ result }) => {
  const id = result.id || {};
  const price = result.price || {};
  return (
    <Col xs={12} md={4}>
      <li className="sui-result product">
        <a
          id="offre_row_3"
          href={"https://www.cliiic.com/offre.php?id=" + id.raw}
          className="col-xs-4"
          ng-repeat="forfait in forfaits"
          style={{ padding: "0px", textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
    {/*MORE STUFF*/}

              {if(price.raw > 0) {
              return (
                <div
                  id={"price_" + id.raw}
                  style={{
                    clear: "both",
                    margin: "5px",
                    float: "right",
                    height: "27px",
                    lineHeight: "27px",
                    fontSize: "15px",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "#FFF",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    position: "relative",
                    display: "block",
                    top: "99px",
                    padding: "0 10px",
                    width: "97px"
                  }}
                >
                <span className="currency">{price.raw}</span>+" $"
              );}}

    {/*MORE STUFF*/}
        </a>
      </li>
    </Col>
  );
};
```

Every examples of the IF/ELSE statement I found trys to use a render() function but I am already in a render at this point and the IF operator crashes the app.

The error returned is:

```
SyntaxError
/src/ResultView.js: Unexpected token (96:15)

  94 |               </div>
  95 | 
> 96 |               {if(price.raw > 0) {
     |                ^
  97 |               return (
  98 |                 <div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here, depending on your situation.

With React, you do not use `if` explicitly when rendering, instead you use a ternary check

```
return <div>{price.raw > 0 ? <your-elements> : ''}</div>;
```

You could also put it into a separate function and call it that way, which is preferred if the condition and data is more complex (and is re-usable)

```
renderPriceDiv(price: { raw: number }, id: { raw: number }): JSX.Element 
{

    if (price.raw > 0) {

        return (
            <div
              id={"price_" + id.raw}
              style={{
                clear: "both",
                margin: "5px",
                float: "right",
                height: "27px",
                lineHeight: "27px",
                fontSize: "15px",
                textAlign: "center",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: "#FFF",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                position: "relative",
                display: "block",
                top: "99px",
                padding: "0 10px",
                width: "97px"
              }}
            >
            <span className="currency">{price.raw}</span>+" $"
          )

    }

    // else
    return <div />;
}
```

Then your `render` function would be something like

```
render() {
    const id = result.id || {};
    const price = result.price || {};

    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderPriceDiv(price, id)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

A third option, as mentioned by @colburton is to call the function and set it to a variable, so render would look something like

```
renderPriceDiv(price: { raw: number }, id: { raw: number }): JSX.Element 
{
    return (
        <div
          id={"price_" + id.raw}
          style={{
            clear: "both",
            margin: "5px",
            float: "right",
            height: "27px",
            lineHeight: "27px",
            fontSize: "15px",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "#FFF",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            position: "relative",
            display: "block",
            top: "99px",
            padding: "0 10px",
            width: "97px"
          }}
        >
        <span className="currency">{price.raw}</span>+" $"
      );
}

render() {
    const id = result.id || {};
    const price = result.price || {};

    const priceDiv = price.raw > 0 ? renderPriceDiv(price, id) : <div />;

    return (
        <div>
            {priceDiv}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `if/else` statements inside a `jsx` expression. Either extract the logic to a custom function which returns `jsx`

```
const Component = () =>{
    const renderStuff = () =>{
        if(condition)
            return <div />

        return <span />
    }

    return (
        <>
            { renderStuff() }
        </>
    )
}
```

Or use `ternary operators` to express a conditional inside the returned block

```
 const Component = () =>{
     return(
         <>
            { condition ? <span /> : <div /> }
         </>
     )
 }
```

Comment: Third option: Save to a variable and output it.

Comment: You can also read [the official React doc about conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) for a more complete understanding.